# Is there inifinite list in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find Haskell's analogue of infinite list in c# language. I want to use any possible interfaces for such list, like these:

> IEnumerable
>
> ICollection
>
> IList

Comment: Given the `yield` keyword in C#, most collection types can be thought to be able to return an infinite list (depending on actual implementation, of course).

Comment: @Oded, this approach can only implement IEnumerable interface. For example, I want to use indexer method for such list. IEnumerable allows only to use foreach semantics

Comment: Then write an indexer, and skip items until you get to the desired index.

Comment: Yes, and as such, is closest to the Haskell "infinite list". You will find that most collections implement `IEnumerable`, so can be used instead of directly specifying that as a return type. I don't know of any Haskell list type that allows you to index into it as you seem to suggest.

Comment: @Oded, Another example is the wish to use IList interface for such type (not IEnumerable). Of course, I can to implement my own List type. But it is tedious work

Comment: If by "infinite list", you mean an endlessly repeating one, check out the [`Cycle` methods in Succinc<T>](https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT/wiki/Cycle). Disclaimer: this library was written by me :)

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` works perfectly fine for infinite sequences. `ICollection<T>` has a `Count` property which makes no sense for infinite sequences, so implementing `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` are rather dubious for infinite collections.

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite your question to be what you actually want, instead of writing a different question then complaining when the answerers failed to read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article on the subject [here](http://www.codethinked.com/infinite-lists-with-c-yield).

Essentially you can utilize the yield keyword to programmatically create the next element of your list.

Comment: Thanks, but such appropach has too narrow possibilities (Note: author uses only IEnumerable interface). Simple Example: I want to use concatenation of simple list and infinite list

Comment: I found useful moment in Article (using Linq laziness). Maybe it will be answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `IEnumerable` and `yield return` you can easily create infinite sets.

```
static IEnumerable<uint> UpDown(uint min = uint.MinValue, uint max = uint.MaxValue, uint step = 1)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("min", "'min' must be less than or equal to 'max'");
    var current = min;
    var last = current;
    var up = true;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return current;
        current += (uint)(up ? step : -step);
        if (up && (current >= max || current < last))
        {
            up = !up;
            current = max;
        }
        else if (!up && (current <= min || current > last))
        {
            up = !up;
            current = min;
        }
        last = current;
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> Random()
{
    while (true)
        yield return 4;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see you've used [RFC 1149.5's specified standard random number](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: ;) ... yeah, I figured a few people would appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The type that most closely corresponds to a lazy Haskell-like list, is `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Comment: Thanks, but such appropach has too narrow possibilities. Simple Example: I want to use concatenation of simple list and infinite list

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко - You can concat a simple list and an infinite list in C# with Linq Concat function, where both are represented by IEnumerable<T>